# Getting rooms availability of exchange server in iPhone

Tags: iphone, outlook, exchange-server

I am creating the room mailbox in exchange server. and sync the exchange into iphone is also done. But how to get the rooms name and timing in iphone. is there any api or frameworks ?

Thanks 
Raj

Answer (score 0):

The Exchange Web Services API can be used to determine room availability:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633709(v=exchg.80).aspx

Since it is a web service, in theory it should be caller agnostic though I don't know how authentication from the iPhone will be handled. I have only used EWS from Windows-based applications, but I know that the iPhone [supports certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244764/iphone-web-service-calls-to-wcf-service-with-certificate-authentication) and obviously it is capable of connecting to Exchange.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing.I tried many times to integrate the EWS in objectiveC. but i had error like "Client The request failed schema validation". I used the sudzc for convert the wsdl to objc file.